# Is Google's Material Icon font designed for anti-aliasing?

Tags: css, fonts, material-design

I'm using Google's Material Icons, and I noticed in the [css they provided](https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons), the option `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` is set. I am a bit confused about this, because my understanding is that most fonts are hinted to prevent blurriness from subpixel rendering. So either

1. The fonts are designed with anti-aliasing in mind, and I should keep the setting, or
2. The person who wrote the css incorrectly decided to ["Fix" the font smoothing](http://usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/)*, and I should ditch the setting.

This is what it looks like for me (very zoomed in). This lends some credence to the first theory, but I only have a Retina screen to test it on, so I don't know how it looks on other screens.

Anti-Aliased:

[image: Anti-Aliased]

Default:

[image: Subpixel]

*The linked article basically says that anti-aliased text is always inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a tough question to answer as it is entirely up to how you would like it and what your expectations are.

In this case, we can't say why it is included in the CSS, we can only assume why it is included. That being that they meant for it to be included.

Although in most cases anti-aliased texts would be a poor choice, when working with these directly, I would assume they were designed to benefit from it.

At the end of the day though, you can always go without it if you prefer it. There are no right or wrong answers to this question as they will all be your personal preference.